# SQL Server 2012 alias does not work outside SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a strange issue with aliases on SQL Server 2012. With SQL Server Management Studio I can connect with the SQL Server alias, but outside SSMS I can not.

For example: I created a file called `Database.udl` and tried to establish a connection with my SQL Server alias, but I cannot do that successfully.

About this topic (aliases and SQL Server) I searched a lot on the internet, but I cannot find a solution that works. Is there anyone who recognise this issue and knows how to solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Comment: Can you connect with the IP of the SQL Server in the UDL?

Comment: Are you talking about aliases in the native client configuration manager? When you say "outside S[S]MS I can not" - are you running on the same machine as the same user account? And: is that code using the same connectivity stack?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'm running SQL Server on the same machine and talking about the native client configuration manager aliases. With my normal IP, for example localhost, I can connect from the outside of SSMS.

Comment: enable the named pipe protocol in configuration manager under sql server network configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the SQL Server Alias to my hostfile. This solves the problem.